References for Projection Properties in Product Topology
Question:
I'm looking for topology textbooks that clearly state or prove the following properties of projections in product spaces:

Open Projection: The projections are open.

Closed Projection: The projections are closed.

Equality with Compactness: In compact spaces, $\mathrm{cl}(\pi_i(W)) = \pi_i(\mathrm{cl}(W))$ for $W \subset X \times Y$.

Interior and Closure of Products:

$\mathrm{int}(U \times V) = \mathrm{int}(U) \times \mathrm{int}(V)$ for open $U \subset X$ and $V \subset Y$.
$\mathrm{cl}(U \times V) = \mathrm{cl}(U) \times \mathrm{cl}(V)$ for any $U \subset X$ and $V \subset Y$.



I’ve checked  Theorem 19.2, 19.5 in Munkres's book and Theorem 8.6 in Willard's General Topology, but I would appreciate other references that address these directly.
Thanks for any suggestions!

I would not recomment a textbook that states or proves (2).

Open(closed) Projection: For an open(closed) set $U \subset X \times Y$, the image $\pi_i(U) \subset X$ is open(closed)

Instead of providing a textbook reference, let me offer directly my own proofs.

If $W$ is open in the product topology on $X\times Y$, then there must exist a non-empty index set $I$, a collection $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of open subsets of $X$, and a collection $(V_i)_{i\in I}$ of open subsets of $Y$ such that $$W=\bigcup_{i\in I}(U_i\times V_i).$$ Without loss of generality, consider the projection $\pi_{X}:X\times Y\to X$ onto the first coordinate. Note that for each $i\in I$, $$\pi_X(U_i\times V_i)=\begin{cases}U_i&\text{if $V_i$ is non-empty,}\\\varnothing&\text{if $V_i=\varnothing$;}\end{cases}$$ in each case, $\pi_X(U_i\times V_i)$ is an open subset of $X$. Since direct images commute with unions, one has $$\pi_X(W)=\pi_X\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}(U_i\times V_i)\right)=\bigcup_{i\in I}\pi_X(U_i\times V_i),$$ which is open in $X$, being a union of open sets.

This is not true. If $X=Y=\mathbb R$, and $$W\equiv\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\,\middle|\,x>0\text{ and }y\geq\frac{1}{x}\right\},$$ then $W$ is closed in $\mathbb R^2$, but $\pi_X(W)=(0,\infty)$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$. But! If $Y$ is compact, then $\pi_X$ is a closed map. (And, analogously, if $X$ is compact, then the projection $\pi_Y:X\times Y\to Y$ onto the second coordinate is a closed map.) To see this, assume that $Y$ is compact and $W\subseteq X\times Y$ is closed. I will show that the complement of $\pi_X(W)$, which I am going to denote by $A$, is open in $X$. This is trivial if $A\equiv X\setminus\pi_X(W)$ is empty. If not, pick any $x\in A$. By definition, one has that $(x,y)\notin W$ for any $y\in Y$. Since $(X\times Y)\setminus W$ is open and $(x,y)$ is in it for any $y\in Y$, there exist open $U_y\subseteq X$ and $V_y\subseteq Y$ such that $$(x,y)\in U_y\times V_y\subseteq (X\times Y)\setminus W.$$ Since $Y$ is compact, there exist some positive integer $n\in\mathbb N$ and $y_1,\ldots,y_n\in Y$ such that $Y=\bigcup_{i=1}^nV_{y_i}$. Define $O_x\equiv\bigcap_{i=1}^nU_{y_i}$. Note that $O_x$ is open in $X$ and that $$\{x\}\times Y\subseteq O_x\times Y\subseteq(X\times Y)\setminus W.$$ From this, it follows relatively easily that $$A=\bigcup_{x\in A}O_x,$$ which completes the proof.

Since $W\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(W)$, it follows that $\pi_X(W)\subseteq\pi_X(\operatorname{cl}(W))$. Note that $\pi_X(\operatorname{cl}(W))$ is closed by 2. above (given that $X$ and $Y$ are compact), from which it follows that $\operatorname{cl}(\pi_X(W))\subseteq\pi_X(\operatorname{cl}(W))$. The other direction $\pi_X(\operatorname{cl}(W))\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(\pi_X(W))$ goes through because $\pi_X$ is continuous, and the image of the closure is included in the closure of the image under a continuous function.

Note: $U$ and $V$ need not be open for this result to hold. Since $\operatorname{int}(U)\subseteq U$, $\operatorname{int}(V)\subseteq V$, $\operatorname{int}(U)\times\operatorname{int}(V)$ is open, and $\operatorname{int}(U\times V)$ is the union of all open sets included in $U\times V$, it follows that $\operatorname{int}(U)\times\operatorname{int}(V)\subseteq\operatorname{int}(U\times V)$. For the other direction, suppose that $\operatorname{int}(U\times V)$ is not empty (the case in which it is empty is trivial). Since $\operatorname{int}(U\times V)$ is open in the product topology, one can represent it as $$\operatorname{int}(U\times V)=\bigcup_{i\in I}(A_i\times B_i),$$ where $I$ is a non-empty index set and, for each $i\in I$, $A_i\subseteq X$ and $B_i\subseteq Y$ are open. There is no loss of generality in assuming that both $A_i$ and $B_i$ are non-empty for every $i\in I$ (otherwise, the product $A_i\times B_i$ could just be omitted from the union), which implies that $A_i\subseteq U$ and $B_i\subseteq V$ for each $i\in I$. The openness of $A_i$ and $B_i$ for each $i\in I$ further implies that $A_i\subseteq\operatorname{int}(U)$ and $B_i\subseteq\operatorname{int}(V)$, so that $A_i\times B_i\subseteq\operatorname{int}(U)\times\operatorname{int}(V)$. Take union over $i\in I$ to conclude that $$\operatorname{int}(U\times V)\subseteq\operatorname{int}(U)\times\operatorname{int}(V).$$
Next, since $U\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(U)$, $V\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(V)$, $\operatorname{cl}(U)\times\operatorname{cl}(V)$ is closed, and $\operatorname{cl}(U\times V)$ is the intersection of all closed sets including $U\times V$, it follows that $\operatorname{cl}(U\times V)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(U)\times\operatorname{cl}(V)$. It remains to prove the other direction, $\operatorname{cl}(U)\times\operatorname{cl}(V)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(U\times V)$. To obtain a contradiction, suppose that $x\in\operatorname{cl}(U)$, $y\in\operatorname{cl}(V)$, but $(x,y)\notin\operatorname{cl}(U\times V)$. Then, $(x,y)\in\operatorname{int}((U\times V)^{\mathsf c})$, where $^{\mathsf c}$ denotes complement. Therefore, there must exist open $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ such that $$(x,y)\in A\times B\subseteq(U\times V)^{\mathsf c}.$$ Since $x\in\operatorname{cl}(U)$ and $y\in\operatorname{cl}(V)$ respectively imply $x\notin\operatorname{int}(U^{\mathsf c})$ and $y\notin\operatorname{int}(V^{\mathsf c})$, it must be the case that $A\not\subseteq U^{\mathsf c}$ and $B\not\subseteq V^{\mathsf c}$. Therefore, there must exist $a\in A\cap U$ and $b\in B\cap V$. But then $$(a,b)\in A\times B\subseteq(U\times V)^{\mathsf c},$$ which contradicts $(a,b)\in U\times V$.



Thank you so much for this detailed response! Appreciate it!

@Bassem You’re welcome, glad to help!
